# MVC View Model show Detail Information

Tags: model-view-controller, detailsview

I hope this makes sense.

I created a class like the following that uses 3 tables (TerrRp, RegMg,DistMg) that I am using in View Model:

```
     public class RepViewModel  

{



    public IEnumerable<TerrRp> TerrRp { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<RegMg> RegMg { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DistMg> DistMg { get; set; } 



}
```

I need to show the Detail info for one of the ables above  (TerrRp table)and not sure how to do it as I am not able to access the fields in the
through something like (in this case I am trying to access the Terr_ID):

```
<div class="display-label">Terr_ID</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Terr_ID)
</div>
```

Meaning, how can I tell DisplayFor to get a hold of the TerrRp table and show the Terr_ID as I need to access RepViewModel first then TerrRp then Terr_ID? Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show a list of associated objects:

Using a strongly typed view with the header

```
@model namespace.RepViewModel
```

You should be able to wind through the TerrRp objects with

```
@foreach (var Rp in Model.TerrRp)
{
    <div class="display-label">Terr_ID</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(Rp  => Rp.Terr_ID)
    </div>
}
```

If you believe that there should only be one object TerrRp associated with the RepViewModel then you could use either First() or FirstOrDefault() methods on IEnumerable

```
<div class="display-label">Terr_ID</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TerrRp.FirstOrDefault().Terr_ID)
</div>
```

You may want to do a count on the Model.TerrRp object to verify that there is one and only one entry.

Comment: Thanks AlexC but as the details is only for 1 record, is there another way of going about this or is this the standard way on how to edit records a ViewModel